# Angular JS output is not changing old output valueA

Tags: angularjs, output, updating

Hi I facing a issue while running a Angular JS program.
when I run the program in visual studio the out put in browser same as previous one or we can say old output value unless the page is refreshed. could any one tell why this is happening. tried in IE firefox n chrome, same result

Answer (score 0):

Please add code. Anyways, if your 'output' is updated outside the digest cycle then it won't update automatically. Try using **$scope.$apply()**. But, adding code would help in understanding the exact problem.